# Authentication and Authorization Micro services on GCP

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform

We have our Microservices written in Java in GCP . We have to implement Authentication and Authorization as those microservices will be accessed from a WEB application. How we can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your requirements are, but for a start, maybe the options at [User Authentication options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/oauth/) can give you some direction!

Comment: Do you have more links toward the Authorization part?